# Camera image projection on displaced geometry

Tags: camera, displacement

trying to get my head around projecting an image onto a mesh that has material displacement. If I use a displace modifier plus UV project it works great but if it is material displacement it projects it to the original non displaced mesh, not factoring in the newly generated geometry.

I am unable to bake out the material displacements due to the nature of the project so I have to find some way to map the camera projection properly to material displaced geometry. Any help in regards to this would be a life saver.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the modifers?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand the issue and your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: As the displacement is done through the material i cannot have it as a modifier. If i did (baking out the displacements as a texture then use a modifier) that would solve the problem. But unfortunately due to the nature of the project we have to be able to map the projection correctly onto displacement done through the material. Thank you.